# MySQL number of days until next occurrence of a date?

Tags: mysql, countdown

I'm looking for a way to have an accurate countdown until Christmas, in number of day. I tried...

```
(SELECT DATEDIFF(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-12-25'), NOW())) as days
```

However this will return a negative date between Christmas and New Years.
I thought I could just add 365 if the number was negative but that won't account for leap years. Any suggestions for a better solution?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty crude, but should do the trick. See if the result is negative, and if so then add one to the year:

```
Select Case DateDiff(Concat(Year(CurDate()), '-12-25'), Now())) < 0
         Then DateDiff(Concat(Year(CurDate())+1, '-12-25'), Now())) 
         Else DateDiff(Concat(Year(CurDate()), '-12-24'), Now())) End As "days"
```

Comment: That works perfectly, don't know why I didn't think of using a CASE clause. Thanks!